# Info window or popup to my marker in mapbox

Tags: popup, mapbox, inf

I have a marker and I want to do is the user can set an information to the marker in `mapbox`. After that, I want to see the marker in map with popup when marker is [clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BixfM.jpg) and contain the informationof user typed. I'm using MYPHPADMİN to save the data. Help Pls.

```
<script>

        var saved_markers = <?= get_saved_locations() ?>;
        var user_location = [121.022606,14.786698];
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2FudG9zcmF2ZW4yMSIsImEiOiJja2p0b2F5dW4yMXMxMnlxbHUxajBsbzgzIn0.ie7znxWwePyJnJbjrWfPLA';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
            center: user_location,
            zoom: 13
        });

        //  geocoder here
        var geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
            accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
            // limit results to Australia
            //country: 'IN',
        });

        map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());

        var marker ;
        // After the map style has loaded on the page, add a source layer and default
        // styling for a single point.
        map.on('load', function() {
            addMarker(user_location,'load');
            add_markers(saved_markers);

            // Listen for the `result` event from the MapboxGeocoder that is triggered when a user
            // makes a selection and add a symbol that matches the result.
            geocoder.on('result', function(ev) {
                alert("Search Found");
                console.log(ev.result.center);

            });
        });
        
        map.on('click', function (e) {
            marker.remove();
            addMarker(e.lngLat,'click');
            //console.log(e.lngLat.lat);
            document.getElementById("lat").value = e.lngLat.lat;
            document.getElementById("lng").value = e.lngLat.lng;

        });

        function addMarker(ltlng,event) {

            if(event === 'click'){
                user_location = ltlng;
            }
            marker = new mapboxgl.Marker({draggable: true,color:"#d02922"})
                .setLngLat(user_location)
                .addTo(map)
                .on('dragend', onDragEnd);
        }

        function add_markers(coordinates) {

            var geojson = (saved_markers == coordinates ? saved_markers : '');

            console.log(geojson);
            // add markers to map
            geojson.forEach(function (marker) {
                console.log(marker);
                // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
                new mapboxgl.Marker()
                    .setLngLat(marker)
                    .addTo(map);
            });

        }

        function onDragEnd() {
            var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
            document.getElementById("lat").value = lngLat.lat;
            document.getElementById("lng").value = lngLat.lng;
            console.log('lng: ' + lngLat.lng + '<br />lat: ' + lngLat.lat);
        }


        $('#signupForm').submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var lat = $('#lat').val();
            var lng = $('#lng').val();
            var url = 'locations_model.php?add_location&lat=' + lat + '&lng=' + lng;
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    location.reload();
                }
            });
        });

        document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(geocoder.onAdd(map));

    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please consider posting in regular case.  All Caps messages are difficult to read at best.  Also please include whatever code you have already (at least, relative portions of it).

Answer (score 0):

you can add the popup that should popup on marker click event, when you initialize the marker:

```js
// create the popup
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }).setText(
'Construction on the Washington Monument began in 1848.'
);
 
// create DOM element for the marker
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.id = 'marker';
 
// create the marker
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
.setLngLat(monument)
.setPopup(popup) // sets a popup on this marker
.addTo(map);
```

Please see this working example of a marker with popup attached:

(Please replace YOUR ACCESS TOKEN to make it work)

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Attach a popup to a marker instance</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.0.1/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
    body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
    #map { position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<style>
    #marker {
        background-image: url('https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/washington-monument.jpg');
        background-size: cover;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .mapboxgl-popup {
        max-width: 200px;
    }
</style>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'YOUR ACCESS TOKEN';
    var monument = [-77.0353, 38.8895];
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
        center: monument,
        zoom: 15
    });

    // create the popup
    var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }).setText(
        'Construction on the Washington Monument began in 1848.'
    );

    // create DOM element for the marker
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.id = 'marker';

    // create the marker
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
        .setLngLat(monument)
        .setPopup(popup) // sets a popup on this marker
        .addTo(map);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```